# finetuned llama2 model generated different result of each GPU

Tags: python, gpu, large-language-model, llama

During the testing process of a model trained on personal data using the llama2 model, I encountered the following issue:

When testing the same model on two GPUs with only the index being different, it produced different results. Specifically, on GPU 0, it generated correct sentences, while on GPU 1, it continued generating sentences until reaching the maximum tokens (i.e., without generating the eos token).

I observed this issue across various models trained using the same approach. Below is the code and an example:

- model load

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

tokenizer_1 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model_1 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_path,
        device_map="cuda:1",
        torch_dtype='auto'
    ).eval()

tokenizer_0 = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model_0 = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_path,
        device_map="cuda:0",
        torch_dtype='auto'
    ).eval()
```

- generation code

```py
prompt = '''Provide the answer to the question. ### Question: {} ### Answer: '''
def gen_standard0(x):
    q = prompt.format(x)
    gened = model_0.generate(
            **tokenizer_0(q,
            return_tensors='pt',
            return_token_type_ids=False).to('cuda:0'),
            temperature=0.5,
            do_sample=True
        )
    return tokenizer_0.decode(gened[0],skip_special_tokens=True).replace(q,"")

def gen_standard1(x):
    q = prompt.format(x)
    gened = model_1.generate(
            **tokenizer_1(q,
            return_tensors='pt',
            return_token_type_ids=False).to('cuda:1'),
            temperature=0.5,
            do_sample=True
        )
    return tokenizer_1.decode(gened[0],skip_special_tokens=True).replace(q,"")
```

- generation

```py
question = 'When should I take aspirin?'

print(f'<<cuda:1 result>>\n')
print(gen_standard1(question).strip())

print(f'\n<<cuda:0 result>>\n')
print(gen_standard0(question).strip())
```

- result cuda:1
  [result cuda:1 (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULE8F.png)
  [result cuda:1 (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uNp.png)
- result cuda:0
  [result cuda:0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKgbh.png)

I couldn't find any differences in the model configuration.
I am using two GPUs (2 RTX 3090s) and utilized autotrain-advanced to train the model using both GPUs.

Here is my working environment:

```
Ubuntu 20.04
CUDA 12.1 Driver 545.23.08
Python 3.10.13
Transformers 4.36.1
Torch 2.1.2
Autotrain-advanced 0.6.80
```

If you have any insights or suggestions, I would appreciate your help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The observed behavior is indeed the expected behavior.
Even though you are using the same parameters for the model as well as for the generation, this does not necessarily mean you will get the same output.

The reason for that is that you set `do_sample=True`.
Therefore, you will have probabilistic behavior which depends on the state of the random number generator at the point of calling `generate()`.

So if it really is your intention to get the exact same output when calling `generate()` multiple times, you can do one of the following things.

### Solution 1 (stick with sampling)

Make sure the random state is the same for each `generate()` call.
You can achieve this through re-setting the seed to any magic number of your choice in between all your `generation()` calls.

```
seed = 42
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
```

**But attention! Just because you are setting your random state to the same porsition as before, this does not necessarily give you the same output. Why? There is still the cache that comes into play... So you will additionally have to use a strategy to deal with your cache (either Solution 1.1 or Solution 1.2)!**

In very easy terms: A "token generation" could still be in the cache from the `generation()` call before and therefore a probabilistic sampling could be skipped for that "token generation", which would result in a different output again.

So if you, e.g., use `meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf` as your base model, then be aware that the default of that is `use_cache=True` (compare [the config on HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf/blob/main/config.json))! And so will be the default for your finetuned version, unless you specify something else.

### Solution 1.1 (caching within a generation)

So if you want to use the cache within a single generation, but not amongst different generations, then you should either pass `use_cache=True` or nothing to the `generation()` call!

And now, to reset the cache in between multiple `generation()` calls, empty the cuda caches as well as the importlib caches.

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
importlib.invalidate_caches()
```

### Solution 1.2 (no caching at all)

To completely deactivate caching of the "token generations", you can pass `use_cache=False` explicitly to the `generation()` call.

## Solution 2 (do not sample)

The other solution, maybe easier, is just not to sample at all.
You can pass `do_sample=False` to your `generate()` calls and remove the temperature parameters (because temperature is only needed in case you sample).

You can read more about the behavior of do_sample in [the docs regarding text-generation on HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#customize-text-generation).

## Another Source of Non-Determinism

Note that I assume you are using the same type of GPU devices for `cuda:0` and `cuda:1` with the same CUDA versions installed. Depending on the type of your devices, you can get different outputs if you compare e.g. GPU type X with GPU type Y.

That means that even if you are using one of the above solutions, you could get different outputs of your `generate()` calls since different GPU types can work differently on a low level.

It happened to me in the past that I was using NVIDIA Quadro RTX and NVIDIA GeForce RTX and I got slightly different results on each device type, even with the same prompts, seeds and cache resets.

[According to the NVIDA forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/different-fp16-inference-behavior-on-four-gpus/253560) you could even get different results on the exact same device (at a granular precision), but for me I could get reliably same results on the same device type using the solutions I suggested now.

Comment: By the way, if you just want to get rid of the repetitive behavior, you can try to play around with the `repetition_penalty` parameter.